# Output send to printer

Tags: c#, c++, printing

How can the output in languages C# and C++ send to printer?

Answer (score 1):

It's O/S-specific, and language-spcific. Different O/Ses, and different (language-specific) run-time-libraries have different APIs.

Assuming you mean Windows (because you talk about C#), some relevent links are:

- C#: [.NET printing](http://www.google.com/#q=.net+printing)
- C++: [GDI Print API](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ff686799(VS.85).aspx)

Comment: Remember, there are systems that run C and C++ that have no printers.

Comment: @Chrisw I used to work with the old Borland C++ and Turbo C about 20 years ago. Back then I recall sending output to a printer by opening a file. Well, that was on DOS. So couldn't we do the same today? I'm afraid I don't recall the exact thing I did but it was done. And in today's context I'm thinking if this is also possible on Ubuntu

Answer (score 0):

There is no standard library support for this in C++, but you can use the [printing mechanism](http://doc.qt.nokia.com/4.6/printing.html) of the [Qt Framework](http://qt.nokia.com/), which is a cross-platform library. Ultimately this functionality is provided by OS-specific APIs, but there are plenty of cross-platform libraries such as Qt that abstract between operating systems. For C#, you may find [this article with an example of printing in C#](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms996492.aspx) to be of use to you.